# How to close current connection at hikariCP pool?

Tags: java, database-connection, pool, hikaricp

I need your help. I use hikariCP for pool connection and i get someone throuble when i create a query to DB. Connection is established and  at DB occur process but response timeline is long about two hours and i want close connection manually. I set timeout   `config.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2L));`
but it not help. It set time for try to connection only but not set time for query and time to get response. How i can manually close connection ?

Comment: Maybe use a transaction with a timeout? Doesn't HikariCP even allow you to put a default timeout? Have you even read the documentation?

Comment: im sorry but i think timeout for try to connection, Is not it so?

Comment: Why do you care about connection timeout? Once you've got your connections in the pool, they're already connected.

Comment: transaction timeout also dont help

Answer (score 0):

I am still unclear what you are trying to do.

If you want the *query* to timeout, call `Statement.setQueryTimeout()` before your long query.

If you simply want the connection to *actually be closed* when you call `Connection.close()`, rather than returning to the pool, with such a long query that is going to happen already.

Why?  Because the default `maxLifetime` is 30 minutes.  So, if you get a connection from HikariCP and use it for 2 hours, it is going to be well past its lifetime.  Therefore, when you call `Connection.close()` HikariCP will immediately evict it from the pool (i.e. close the actual DB connection).